# Using Textures With GLSL Shaders for iOS With OpenGL ES 2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

This information doesn't exist on Google somehow.

I need to transfer texture coordinates to my shader programs but ATTRIB_TEXCOORD doesn't exist. What do I do with glVertexAttribPointer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a shader program and the name of the texture attribute (in this example the attribute is named “textureCoords”) you get the index like this:

```
int a_texture = glGetAttribLocation(program, "textureCoords");
```

and then use a_texture in glVertexAttribPointer like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(a_texture, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
```